# Get value into variable in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to enter some command value into a variable, I’ve tried with the following which doesn't work, what could be missing here?

```
OUTPUT=git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{$NF+=1; OFS="."; print $0}'
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

For this I got

```
OUTPUT="git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk -F. '{F+=1; OFS="."; print }'"
echo ""
```

even if I remove the quote it doesn't work...

Comment: @that other guy - why, i’ve read it already and try exactly like the first answer and it doesnt works…\

Comment: The first answer being the accepted one? It does work. Please update your question and show what's wrong when you apply it (with actual and expected result)